# Creating an EventHandler Bukkit

Tags: minecraft, bukkit, eventhandler

i'm trying to create a @EventHandler, but im not sure where im supposed to put it or create a new file? If you could sample some code. (Im new to this)

Comment: Please look at the wiki. It explains everything.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here should __show research effort or attempts__. Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score 1):

You can either create a new file or include it in your main plugin file or a separate file. Here is an example using the main file:

```
public class BukkitExample extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        //Code to execute when a player joins
    }
}
```

Either way, you will need to `implement Listener` and register the events with the plugin manager. `EventHandler` is not a class that you are extending; it is an annotation. You can [read the Event API Reference](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Event_API_Reference), and check [the javadocs](http://jd.bukkit.org/) for a list of events and their methods.